# how to write a general javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I have the following javascript code

```
$(function(){
    // loading source image
   $('#panel').mousemove(function(e) { // binding mouse move event
       // some code
   });
   $('#panel').mousedown(function(e) { // binding mousedown event
       // some code
   });
   $('#panel').mouseup(function(e) { // binding mouseup event
       // some code
   });
});

function getResults() {
    // some code
}
```

which works in this way

```
<button onclick="getResults()">Crop</button>
<canvas id="panel" width="100" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

I would like to re-write this js-plugin to make it more general.
I suppose a good way to use it is the following way:

```
$('#panel').myLib({
    onSelect: getResults,
    onClick: getResults
});
```

Any ideas how should I rewrite the my js code to get this result?
thanks

Comment: I'd suggest starting [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `fn` property (which is actually an alias for `prototype`) to add a plugin:

```
$.fn.myLib = function(options){

  // bind events
  this.mousemove(function(e) { // binding mouse move event
    // some code
  });
  this.mousedown(function(e) { // binding mousedown event
    // some code
  });
  this.mouseup(function(e) { // binding mouseup event
    // some code
  });

  // add a button
  this.before($('<button>').text('Crop').click(options.onSelect));

  // return the object to make the function chainable
  return this;
};
```